# Prevent Job execution if job was scheduled to be executed in the past?

Tags: hangfire

I'm looking for a way to prevent Hangfire from executing a job which has been scheduled to be executed in the past. For instance, if Product import is scheduled to be run at 4am, but server goes down and only comes back up at 7am, Hangfire it execute the 4am job immediately. I want to prevent this, any ideas?

What complicates matters, is that I still want to be able to execute the job manually when necessary, so I cannot hard-code a check to make sure job doesn't execute outside of 4am window.

Any ideas would be welcome.

More here https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/620